# Example where Raabe's Test is inconclusive

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was looking for an example of a convergent series for which the Raabe's test is inconclusive. I found the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\operatorname{log}^2n}$, which can easily be shown to be convergent. However, I couldn't calculate the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} n\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} -1 \right)$ because it got really messy.

Can someone either find a nicer way to calculate this limit, or give a different example of a convergent series for which the Raabe's test is inconclusive?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raabi's test is designed to capture the essence of a $p$-series. Indeed, if we set

$$ p = \lim_{n\to\infty} n \left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} - 1\right), \tag{*} $$

then it is not hard to show that $a_n = \frac{1}{n^{p+o(1)}}$, provided $p$ exists. Now using $\frac{1}{n\log^2 n} = \frac{1}{n^{1+o(1)}}$, we find that either the limit $\text{(*)}$ does not converge or we have $p = 1$, in either case the test is inconclusive.

A more direct computation is also available. If $a_n = \frac{1}{n\log^2 n}$, then

\begin{align*}
\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}
&= \frac{(n+1)\log^2(n+1)}{n \log^2 n} \\
&= \biggl(1 + \frac{1}{n}\biggr)\biggl(1 + \frac{2\log(1+1/n)}{\log^2 n} + \frac{\log^2(1+1/n)}{\log^2 n} \biggr).
\end{align*}

Now by noting that $\log(1+1/n) = \mathcal{O}(1/n)$, this yields the asymptotic formula

$$ n \left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} - 1\right) = 1 + \mathcal{O}\biggl(\frac{1}{\log^2 n}\biggr). $$

This converges to $1$ as $n \to \infty$, showing $p = 1$ in this case.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$n\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=(n+1)\Bigl(\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)}\Bigr)^2$$

$$\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)}=1+\frac{\ln(1+\frac 1n)}{\ln(n)}$$